# how i can convert char array to int without use parseInt and String.valueOf() (java)

Tags: java, arrays, char, integer

need to convert char array to int **without use parseInt and String.valueOf()**,

***need to realize this method***

```
public static int parseInt(char[] str) {
  
}
```

for example, if the input data is `char[] str  = {'-','1','2','3'};`

need to show:

`int result = parseInt(str);`

`System.out.println(result);`
// **-123**

Comment: Could you explain *why* you don't want to use the standard approaches? The motivation can easily affect the answer someone would post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to work for your case

```
public static int parseInt(char[] str) {
        int result = 0;
        int start = 0;
        boolean negative = false;
        if(str[0] == '-') {
            start = 1;
            negative = true;
        }
        for (int i = start; i < str.length; i++)
        {
            
            int digit = (int)str[i] - (int)'0';
            if ((digit < 0) || (digit > 9)) throw new NumberFormatException();
            result *= 10;
            result += digit;
        }
        if(negative) {
            result = 0 - result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] str = {'-', '1', '2', '3'};
    int[] charToInt = new int[str.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        charToInt[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charToInt));
}
```

**Mb something like this, but I'm not sure about the first character**

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but thanks)